# jQuery function doesn't work first time, works perfectly after that

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a jQuery animation that is performed when the button is clicked, it works fine after the first time. Instead of smoothly animating its height (it should "slide" up to its full size) it just pops out the first time and after that it works fine every time.

Also on disappearing of the element you can still see the element fade out, how to remove this? It is especially visible when having an element directly underneath it.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>A title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- search input (style & php (WHERE ifset)), fix animation for input, text -->

<style>

body{
font-family: "Verdana", Times, sans-serif;
}

.topBar{
background-color:#151515;
height:75px;
font-size:1.55em;
}

#mainDiv{
background-color:#DAA520;
min-height:400px;
}

.topMenuDiv{
width:250px;
color:#DAA520;
border:5px #DAA520 solid;
border-radius:35px;
background-color:inherit;
padding:10px;
margin-top:4px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

#id1{
background-color:#151515;
display:none;
}

#closeButton{
width:50px;
color:#DAA520;
background-color:inherit;
border:5px #DAA520 solid;
border-radius:35px;
padding:5px;
margin-left:90%;
}

#bottomDiv{
height:150px;
background-color:#151515;
}

</style>

  </head>
  <body>

<div class = "container">
<div class="row">

<div class = "topBar col-md-12 col-md-6"></div>

<div class = "topBar col-xs-6 col-md-3">
<button class = "topMenuDiv buttonHE" id = "button1">
<div>Click for effect</div>
</button>
</div>


<div class = "topBar col-xs-6 col-md-3">
<a href = ""><div class="topMenuDiv buttonHE">Info?</div></a>
</div>
</div>

<div class = "row col-xs-12"   id = "id1">

<button type="button" class = "buttonHE class1" id = "closeButton">&times;</button>

<form   class = "class1"  action = "" method="post">
<p>
Just some text Just some text Just some text Just some text Just some text 
Just some text Just some text Just some text Just some text Just some text 
Just some text Just some text Just some text Just some text Just some text 
Just some text Just some text Just some text Just some text Just some text 
</p>
</form>

</div>

<div class = "row" id = "mainDiv">
</div>
</div> 
</div>

<div class = "container">
<div class="row">
<div class = "col-xs-12 col-md-12" id = "bottomDiv"></div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<script>

$(".buttonHE").mouseenter(function(){
     $(this).css("color", "#151515");
     $(this).css("background-color", "#DAA520");
<!-- $(this).css("border-color", "#151515"); -->
}); 

$(".buttonHE").mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).css("color", "#DAA520");
     $(this).css("background-color", "#151515");
     $(this).css("border-color", "#DAA520");
}); 

$var1 = $('#id1').outerHeight();
$("#mainDiv").html($var1);

$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#button1").click(function(){
      $("#id1").css("display", "unset"); 
      $("#id1").animate({height: $var1});
      $(".class1").fadeIn(300);
}); 
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#closeButton").click(function(){
      $(".class1").fadeOut();
      $("#id1").animate({height: '0px'});
      $("#id1").fadeOut();
}); 
});




</script>


<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<!-- $(this).css("border-color", "#151515"); -->` is invalid JavaScript. You have to use JavaScript comments, not HTML comments.

Comment: Why are you including bootstrap twice? That would cause a lot of handlers to be declared twice

Comment: Have you checked what console says?

Comment: As @amenadiel has noticed, you are loading `bootstrap(.min).js` twice. This alone spills a lot of blood in your console. Make a habit of checking the console whenever you encounter errors. Most times, searching the error output will lead you to the root of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try to put your `js/bootstrap.min.js` library on the top before your JQuery functions, so that it will load first.
Changes From

```
<script>
$(".buttonHE").mouseenter(function(){
     $(this).css("color", "#151515");
     $(this).css("background-color", "#DAA520");
<!-- $(this).css("border-color", "#151515"); -->
}); 

$(".buttonHE").mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).css("color", "#DAA520");
     $(this).css("background-color", "#151515");
     $(this).css("border-color", "#DAA520");
}); 

$var1 = $('#id1').outerHeight();
$("#mainDiv").html($var1);

$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#button1").click(function(){
      $("#id1").css("display", "unset"); 
      $("#id1").animate({height: $var1});
      $(".class1").fadeIn(300);
}); 
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#closeButton").click(function(){
      $(".class1").fadeOut();
      $("#id1").animate({height: '0px'});
      $("#id1").fadeOut();
}); 
});


</script>


<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
```

TO

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

<script>

$(".buttonHE").mouseenter(function(){
     $(this).css("color", "#151515");
     $(this).css("background-color", "#DAA520");
// $(this).css("border-color", "#151515"); Or just remove this line
}); 

$(".buttonHE").mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).css("color", "#DAA520");
     $(this).css("background-color", "#151515");
     $(this).css("border-color", "#DAA520");
}); 

$var1 = $('#id1').outerHeight();
$("#mainDiv").html($var1);

$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#button1").click(function(){
      $("#id1").css("display", "unset"); 
      $("#id1").animate({height: $var1});
      $(".class1").fadeIn(300);
}); 
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#closeButton").click(function(){
      $(".class1").fadeOut();
      $("#id1").animate({height: '0px'});
      $("#id1").fadeOut();
}); 
});

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

on the bottom of your code, you need to add a style on your #id1 height: "0px":

```
//...
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#id1").css({ height: "0px" });
});
</script>
```

this will solve your problem

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. This solved the style problem.